# Use Function Based Index on COUNT DISTINCT?

Tags: oracle

I have the following query which takes takes about 23 - 30 seconds to execute. The Sample Table has 2.8 Million rows and the test Table has 21.1 Million rows. 
I have indexes on Primary Keys Sample Number and Test Number but the count(distinct) clause is causing a severe hit on performance. Can I use a Function Based Index on a COUNT DISTINCT to improve the performance?

```
    select  
    l.NAME as LABORATORY,
    count(distinct s.SAMPLE_NUMBER), 
    count(distinct (case when l.NAME ='LPS' and t.BATCH is null then s.SAMPLE_NUMBER
    else null end)) LPS   
    from LABORATORY l  inner join SAMPLE s on l.NAME = s.LAB 
    inner join TEST t on s.SAMPLE_NUMBER = t.SAMPLE_NUMBER 
    and s.STATUS <> 'U'  and s.TEMPLATE <> 'QC_SAMPLE' and t.STATUS in ('I', 'P')
    group by l.NAME;
```

Comment: Insufficient data: how many rows in each table satisfy the join condition? Are there other indexes? average size of the rows in each table? Also of course it would help to have the actual **optimizer plan**! *In general* the simple calculation like a simple `CASE` take orders of magnitude **less** resource and time than actually finding the rows (which looks like a big FULLSCAN + HASH JOIN).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is: **NO**, you cannot use a function based index in this case.
An index (any index) can be created only on columns coming from ONE table.
The expression in COUNT references three tables: l + t + s

```
count(distinct (case when l.NAME ='LPS' and t.BATCH is null then s.SAMPLE_NUMBER
    else null end)) LPS
```